# Setting errorContainer multiple times in a form

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form `$('#myForm')` that has two divs `$('#myDiv1')`, `$('#myDiv2')`, with two text fields in each. I would like a single `errorContainer` for each of the two divs.

If I call `$('#myForm').validate({ ... });` I can only specify a single `errorContainer`, which isn't what I want.

If I call `$('#myDiv1').validate({ ... });` I get an error from within jquery-validate: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined`. This leads me to presume that I cannot call validate on anything but a form.

Is there a way I can do what I want?

Comment: Just an FYI:  `$('form').validate()` is called _once_ on DOM ready to _initialize_ the plugin on the `form`.  It should not be called multiple times and, as you already discovered, you cannot call it on an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
$("#myform").validate({
   errorPlacement: function(error, element) {}
});
```

Where the 'element' is the jQuery object of the current form input. It's in http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

Answer (score 0):

The validate method *must* be called on a form element.

I haven't used this in practice, but the [options docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) seem to indicate you can pass multiple selectors for the errorContainer option.

```
$("#myform").validate({
   errorContainer: "#messageBox1, #messageBox2",
   errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox1 ul",
   wrapper: "li", debug:true,
   submitHandler: function() { alert("Submitted!") }
});
```

Comment: [Additional markup is required for your code to work as intended in the doc's example](http://jsfiddle.net/yZdDE/).  Regardless, still not quite what the OP is asking for.